# Filter a dataset based on a text parameter that allows multiple values in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, varchar

I have an SSRS parameter that allows to select multiple values of type varchar.
How can I get my `where` clause to show all those selected in the parameter. An example is if the parameter choices were

```
1 : Rob
2 : Tom
3 : Rick
```

If the first two choices were selected, there should be 2 records. Something to the effect:

```
where Employee.Code + ' : ' + Employee.Name IN ("1 : Rob","2 : Tom")
```

Comment: Is your parameter returning both code & name columns as one value?

Comment: Were you able to sort this out?

Answer (score 0):

If the parameter value is returning both the "employee code" and "employee name", then I'd use a [CTE (Common Table Expression)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx) to create the concatenated column before filtering it. You may want to create the CTE in a view if you're going to use it elsewhere.

```
WITH
employee
AS
(
    SELECT tbl.* FROM (VALUES
      ( 1, 'Rob')
    , ( 2, 'Tom')
    , ( 3, 'Rick')
    ) tbl ([code], [name]) 
)
,
employee_values
AS
(
    SELECT 
          [code]
        , [name]
        , [code_name] = CAST([code] AS VARCHAR) + ' : ' + [name]
    FROM    
        employee    
)
SELECT 
      [code]
    , [name]
    , [code_name]
FROM 
    employee_values
WHERE 
    [code_name] IN(@Employee_Code)
```